# java displaying and formatting with printf

Tags: java, arrays, format, printf

I have a question on how to display with `printf`. I used printf four times. The first two and last times, it worked fine. The third one did not. I want it to have the same format as the other values. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. I used the format `%15.2f` to display it and when I compile and execute it, it just gives me this:

```
run:
    Mercury          Venus          Earth           Mars        Jupiter         Saturn         Uranus        Neptune          Pluto
    2439.70        6051.90        6378.00        3402.50       71492.00       60270.00           25562.00       24774.00        1195.00
330220000000000000000000.004868500000000000000000000.005973600000000001000000000.00641850000000000000000000.001898600000000000200000000000.00568459999999999960000000000.0086810000000000000000000000.00102430000000000000000000000.0013120000000000000000000.00
       3.70           8.87           9.79           3.70          24.78          10.44           8.86          11.13           0.61
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Below is a snippet of my code (the place where I used printf for the third time has extra '/':

```
public static void printResults(String[] name, double[] radius, double[] mass, double[] gravity)
{
        // fill in code here
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%15s", name[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%15.2f", radius[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        //////////////////
        for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%15.2f", mass[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < gravity.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%15.2f", gravity[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
}

//print the gravity values to text file
public static void printToFile(double[] gravity)throws IOException
{
    // fill in code here
}

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    // Initialize variables
    String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
    double[] masses = {3.3022 * Math.pow(10,23), 4.8685 * Math.pow(10,24), 5.9736 * Math.pow(10,24), 6.4185 * Math.pow(10,23),
                1.8986 * Math.pow(10,27), 5.6846 * Math.pow(10,26), 8.6810 * Math.pow(10,25), 1.0243 * Math.pow(10,26), 1.312 *
                    Math.pow(10,22)};
    // or using big E notation:
    // double [] mass = {3.30E23, 4.87E24, 5.97E24, 6.42E23, 1.90E27, 5.68E26, 8.68E25, 1.02E26, 1.27E22}; // See IMACS double lesson for big E notation

    // Processing
    double[] gravities = calcGravity(radii, masses);
```

Comment: The mass values are longer than 15 digits. `330220000000000000000000` is 24 digits. You can either make the columns wider, or use a more compact representation for the masses: e.g., `3.3022e23`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output looks weird because the mass values are quite long, especially when printed as decimal numbers. printf doesn't truncate values that exceed the given field width.

You might want to use e when printing the masses instead. It'll print the values out in a scientific notation which is probably better suited for large values.

```
for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++){
    System.out.printf("%15.2e", mass[i]);
}
```